# Web fonts not showing over HTTPS on IE11 windows 7 with no-cache option header set using helmet

Tags: node.js, express, internet-explorer-11, webfonts, helmet.js

I have an error that only occurs in Win 7 IE11, webfonts font-awesome and glyphicons are not showing over https, but do over http. After some research I found that the fonts wont load with no-cache in header.

Im using express and app.use(helmet.noCache());, does anyone know if I can exclude fonts from this?

Answer (score 1):

Helmet's `noCache` middleware has no way to exclude specific paths/files. (I'm the maintainer of Helmet, just FYI!)

You can take advantage of Express's middleware ordering to accomplish something like this. Don't `app.use` the `noCache` middleware until you've `app.use`d the middleware that serves your fonts. Something like this:

```
app.use(express.static(PATH_TO_FONTS))
app.use(helmet.noCache())
```